# The correct and prudent TFS 2018 reboot sequence

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We are running an onprem Tfs2018 (16.122.27102.1) server. The topology consists of 4 separate servers (Server 2016):

- Application Server (Tfs app and reporting server)
- Data Server (SQL Server 2016)
- Build Server (where all build agents are running)
- Code Search Server

The question stems from the fact that the department responsible for windows updates, will be doing this in an unattended way. 
This inevitably will cause rebooting in a random sequence.

I am trying to figure out what the correct and prudent TFS 2018 reboot sequence would look like, and if it is scriptable.
I was thinking of something in the lines of:

**1 - Stopping Tfs**:

- Disable build agents, and wait till all builds in progress have competed, the rest should pend (via Rest API)
- Stop all collections (scriptable?)
- Run TFSServiceControl quiesce
- Run PauseSearchIndexing.ps1  [Code Search Admin scripts found at: https://github.com/Microsoft/Code-Search]

**2 - Execute the maintenance:**

- In this case windows updates

**3 - After start-up:** (all servers are booted up)

- TFSServiceControl unquiesce
- Start all collections (scriptable?)
- Enable all build agents (via Rest API)
- Run StartSearchIndexing.ps1 [Code Search Admin scripts found at: https://github.com/Microsoft/Code-Search]

Is there perhaps a far less complicated way to achieve this?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've been working with TFS in one capacity or another for about 10 years now and I've never heard of anything like this being necessary. I think you're overthinking it.

I've rebooted running app and data tiers thousands of times and never had a problem.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Then I will lay this nagging concern to rest. The robustness of Tfs never ceases to amaze me!

Answer (score 0):

We are at the point where we need to, possibly, add some steps into our Windows updates process.
On several occasions we end up with TFS server showing all build/deployment agents online but services on build/deployment servers are not running.
Trying to start them as a service is not working. Rebooting build/deploy server does nothing. Running run.cmd shows attempt of the agent to connect to the server but failing because it is already used/connected by the same owner...
So far, we found two "fixes":

1. Reboot TFS main server (not always possible at that very moment).
2. Uncofigure/remove agent and reinstall it.

It is unknown the root cause, could be that TFS server/services have to be stopped first to avoid it.

Something like this:

- TFSServiceControl quiesce
- [Do updates]
- TFSServiceControl unquiesce

Also, any build or deployment will fail if TFS server is rebooting while they are running. This may be a problem for some folks.
Disable any builds/deployments for maintenance window (update schedule) to avoid this. It may be simpler comparing to complicated checks and wait for all processed to finish (some may have very long running builds or deployments).
Alternative is to restart failed builds after maintenance is over.

I'll try to post here what we add to the process. It may take some time to verify the solution (based on schedule for Windows updates and the fact that this issue is not happening every time).

Note: We use TFS 2017 on-prem with deployment agents in multiple domains using PAT for authentication.